# php - counting rows values

Tags: php, sql

```
            $teams_w = $da['win'];
            $teams_d = $da['draw'];
            $teams_l = $da['lost'];
            $teams_p = $da['points'];
            $teams_m = $teams_w+teams_d+teams_l;
```

Is this correct?

Because the $teams_m is only counting the $teams_w value.

Comment: Probably the other two values are `0`. Show us more code (more context, like the SQL query).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$teams_m = $teams_w + $teams_d + $teams_l;
```

You hadn't put the `$` to state they are variables in your sum